# Find a string in a table and return a value

Tags: windows, command-line, cmd, findstr

Imagine this `.txt` file:

```
Example.txt

Row    Column1    Column2    Column3 <br>
1       aaa         bbb        ccc<br>
2       ddd         eee        fff
```

How can I get a value in the table using the command line?

Ex. : (Row=2, Column2) returns value "eee".
Ex. : (Row=1, Column3) returns value "ccc".

I'm trying `findstr` but I don't know how to implement it.

Comment: Is the row number information physically in the file as the 1st column?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the row info is actually in the file, and assuming no values contain spaces:

```
@echo off
call :getValue  2  Column2  "Example.txt"
call :getValue  1  Column3  "Example.txt"
call :getValue  0  Column1  "Example.txt"
call :getValue  1  DoesNotExist  "Example.txt"
exit /b

:getValue
setlocal
<%3 set /p "header="
set token=0
for %%C in (%header%) do (
  set /a token+=1
  if %%C==%2 goto columnFound
)
echo Column %2 not found in %3
exit /b

:columnFound
for /f "tokens=%token%" %%A in ('findstr /blc:"%1 " %3') do (
  echo %3 (Row=%1, %2^) = %%A
  exit /b
)
echo Row %1 not found in %3
exit /b
```

Results

```
"Example.txt" (Row=2, Column2) = eee
"Example.txt" (Row=1, Column3) = ccc
Row 0 not found in "Example.txt"
Column DoesNotExist not found in "Example.txt"
```